# Scheduling a Script without cron and at commands

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, cron, at-job

I'm working on a proprietary  Linux based server which does not have cron and at utilities.
Nor does it allow me to install the same
Can any one help me out in scheduling a particular task without these two utilities

Comment: you can create your own cron. try creating script which runs every `n` interval of time just to check a file for scheduled job and execute accordingly.

Comment: would you be able to add a daemon written in C?

Comment: most scripting language has already a library that allows such function
the easiest would be writing your own script with any language you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

golang is compiled to a static binary 
you can easily use the following library https://godoc.org/github.com/robfig/cron
to create code that will run a given text file as cron data.